# How would I graph a scatter plot from a 2d array, where the size of the markers is determined by the values in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to understand the scatter function in matplotlib and I've got myself stuck.
So I've got an array (generated below), and I wanted to use the index values as axis and then the values in the array itself to determine the size of the markers. I know that I'm doing something very wrong I just can't figure out what.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec 12 18:36:01 2022

@author: Luke
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = 11
z_list = np.arange(z)
z_list_copy = np.zeros(z)

z_combo = np.zeros((z,z))

z_combo[0,0] = 1

for i in range(1,z):
    for j in range(z):
        z_combo[i,j] = z_combo[i-1,j-1] + z_combo[i-1,j]

print(z_combo)

plt.scatter(z,z, s=z_combo[i,j])
```

I was kinda hoping for a graph that looked like a visualization of this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS1Ky.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to plot the values of `z_combo` in a two-dimensional scatter plot, in which case you need to specify both the x and y coordinates for each point.

```
   x, y = np.where(z_combo > 0)
   plt.scatter(x, y, s=z_combo[x, y])
```

Comment: You want to use `scatter(y, -x)` to get things in the same order as the printed representation. https://i.imgur.com/kycCJan.png